# Unit testing a very specific function

Tags: unit-testing, function, aggregation, vendor

To make sure this question is concrete enough for the standards in the FAQ, I am just asking the following: What are some sources that discuss the most common ways to apply unit testing to a very specific function, generally a function that relies on vendor data or other very specific data such that synthetic data is unhelpful in the test? If you're interested in more background, read below.

**Background:**

I write unit tests often in my daily code development, but I also try to make my code as abstract and reusable as possible. In a new project that I've joined, there are many cases where the code consists of very specific functions that are meant to accept very specifically formatted input data and store output data to database tables. Much of the input data consists of vendor data or other in-house data, and is accessed through calls to both vendor and in-house APIs.

The only idea I have so far is to test the kinds of failures hit upon when input data is poorly formatted. I will definitely write this test, but it's pretty useless for our team as far as tests go. Much more useful tests ought to check that the logic of these data manipulations is correct, which involves checking the accuracy of the output data based on the input data.

Unfortunately, I don't have any benchmark data sets where I definitively know what the output should be. Others have suggested to create my own synthetic input data (like a matrix of all 1's or something contrived where I can predict what the output should be). Unfortunately, the operations performed by the function are very non-linear (binning things by weighted percentiles and getting aggregate statistics over each percentile grouping). Any test of this that's based off of totally contrived synthetic input data won't be very useful for us either, and the time cost of formatting it and then writing to some synthetic output database table and reading it to check in the unit test kind of makes such a test worthless.

I know that unit tests should test for just one behavior. I'm just not sure how to break apart a function that does something like aggregating complicated statistics across weighted percentile groupings and boil that down to "just one thing" to test.

What are some standards used in this setting?

Comment: better suited on http://programmers.stackexchange.com maybe?!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues with very large methods. My advice would be to refactor the code utilizing Dependency Injection and adhering to the Single Responsibility Principle. Then test each class according to its responsibility.